# Scrapy won't get results from first page

Tags: scrapy

here is my spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from vrisko.items import VriskoItem

class vriskoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'vrisko'
    allowed_domains = ['vrisko.gr']
    start_urls = ['http://www.vrisko.gr/search/%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%84%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%82/%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%B4%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%BF']
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\?page=\d')), callback='parse_vrisko'),
    )
    def parse_vrisko(self, response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        vriskoit = VriskoItem()
        vriskoit['eponimia'] = hxs.select("//a[@itemprop='name']/text()").extract()
        vriskoit['address'] = hxs.select("//div[@class='results_address_class']/text()").extract()
        print ' '.join(vriskoit['eponimia']).join(vriskoit['address'])
        return vriskoit
```

The pages i try to crawl have the format http://www.blabla.com/blabla/bla?page=x
where x = any integer.

My problem is that my spider crawls all pages except the first one!
Any ideas why does this happen ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

if you look into scrapy doc , start_urls  response goes to **

> parse

** method

so you can change your rule like this

`rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\?page=\d')), callback='parse'),
    )`

and method name from `def parse_vrisko(self, response):` to `def parse(self, response):`

or you can remove start_urls and start your spider  with `def start_requests(self):` with callback to `parse_vrisko`

Comment: Thank you very much,but i found the answer. I have replaced parse_vrisko with parse_start_url